# Do i need to delete existing Postgresql schema before restoring it from backup

Tags: postgresql, schema, restore

I'm trying to restore a schema to the DB, where there are 2 schemas.

I need to restore only one, replace it, not affecting the other.
I'm doing this:

```
pg_restore -d db_name -h localhost -U user_name  -n schema_name < path/file_name.sql
```

and getting an error:

```
pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT "db_name.wrong_values wrong_values_mistake_id_fkey"

pg_restore: from TOC entry 3116; 2606 29161362 FK CONSTRAINT wrong_values wrong_values_mistake_id_fkey postgres

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  constraint "wrong_values_mistake_id_fkey" for relation "wrong_values" already exists

Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY db_name.wrong_values

    ADD CONSTRAINT wrong_values_mistake_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (mistake_id) REFERENCES db_name.mistake_types(id);
```

Do i need to drop a schema first? Before restoring it?

Can you tell, how to do it right, not affecting the other schema?

Comment: Restore is a replace in place method. It cannot know what is already there or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, yes.
If we don't have any connections between schemas, then we need to do in DB query first:

```
DROP SCHEMA schema_name CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA schema_name;
```